What are the differences between PS-match and adjusted Cox regression?
This is more like an extension of the following question: Propensity Score Matching with Cox Regression
I am wondering what are the differences between these:

matching patients with PS and running Cox regression with only the exposure as the predictor
running Cox regression with all covariates (that I would have used in PS match)

Will these methods lead to different conclusions, and when should I use which method?

Have you seen my post here?

There are huge differences.  Suppose for example that age is a strong predictor of time until event.  Adjusting for outcome heterogeneity due to age clarifies the picture is makes the proportional hazards assumption more likely to hold.  Failure to include age as a covariate means you are modeling a mixture of survival time distributions that may even be bimodal.  When you do not account for easily accounted-for outcome heterogeneity the effects of other covariates in the model (such as treatment) are attenuated.  I.e., the hazard ratio for treatment will be biased towards 1.0 if you don’t account for outcome heterogeneity.  For more problems with propensity scores see here.
